# Issue using Type Punning with union

Tags: c, union, type-punning, c-standard-library

I wanted to learn more about type punning and aliasing. So I use the code provide by the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) at option `-fstric-aliasing` like below :

```c
union a_union{
    int i;
    double d;
};

int f(){
    union a_union t;
    t.d=3.0;

    return t.i
}

/*what I add*/
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n",f());
    return 0;
}
```

I expected nothing special but I get only 0. So I test with different value for `t.d` but no change.
I test this code on Debian 9, with gcc 6.3, without option.
I also try with option `-fno-strict-aliasing` same result

If someone can I explain, why I get only 0 that would be great

Comment: There's `a_union` and `q_union` in your code. Is this actually your code, or have you made a mistake copy-pasting it?

Comment: Oh, that's just because I use two computers one with an azerty keyboard, and the other one with a qwerty, so sometimes I make mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sizes of the members do not match in any common systems. `int` is usually nowadays 32 bits and `double` 64 bits. Because of little-endian storage, the zero bits at the end of the `3.0000000000` correspond to those of the `int` member.

Try this one instead:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

union q_union{
    uint64_t i;
    double d;
};

_Static_assert(sizeof (union q_union){}.i == sizeof (union q_union){}.d,
     "The sizes of double and uint64_t must match");

uint64_t f(void) {
    union q_union t;
    t.d = 3.0;
    return t.i;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", f());
    printf("%#" PRIx64 "\n", f());
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
4613937818241073152
0x4008000000000000
```

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on the type of storage used by your particular processor.

3.0000000000000000 (double precision 3) is represented by 4008 0000 0000 0000 (hex)

Your processor could store floating point numbers in a variety of orders, some store the least significant bytes/words first. In that case the int would only return 0000 0000.

Try using Pi, or sqrt(2)

Answer (score 0):

A `double` with value `3.0` has a lot of 0 bytes.  I assume the endianess of your machine is such that they overlap with the int.  If instead of `3.0` you are using `3.1`, you should see another value.

Instead of an `int`, you may also try with an `unsigned long long`, it commonly has the same size as a double and you'll be able to print its whole representation.